# Is there a difference between pwd and cd?

Tags: cd-command, pwd

Is there a difference between `pwd` and `cd` (no arguments)? They both print the current directory's path but is there a subtle difference that I'm missing, and if so, when should I use which?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, they are completely different commands that do different things.

`pwd` prints the directory you are currently in. It does nothing else.`pwd` does not take any arguments.

`cd` **without arguments** *changes* your working directory to your home directory. It does not print anything by default.

`cd` **with an argument** will change your working directory to whatever directory you supplied as an argument.

Comment: Thanks. I must have misremembered about `cd` with no arguments. Sorry.

Comment: `pwd` does take a couple of arguments, the options `-L` and `-P` (for "logical" and "physical"). These flags happen to be supported (with the same meanings) by the `cd` command too.

Answer (score 3):

`cd` changes to your home directory, I think this is a more than subtle difference.

I suggest reading the `man` page before asking in a forum.

Answer (score 1):

The command

```
pwd
```

shows the current directory, while the command

```
cd
```

will change directory to your home directory.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the below command to find out where the previous command was executed and get on the folder.

```
cd -
```

In contrast, pwd only gives you the path of the current working directory.